# A list has multiple strings so I want to do concatenation of two strings if one string of character doesn't exist in another string

Tags: python, string

```
def conc():
    l1=l
    print(l1[-1])
    for i in range(len(l1)-1):
        if l1[i] not in l1[i+1]:
            s=l1[i]+l1[i+1]
            print(s)
        if l1[i] not in l1[-1]:
            s1=l1[i]+l1[-1]
            print(s1)

l=ast.literal_eval(input())
conc()
```

Given

```
l=["abc","yyy","def","csv"]
```

The result should be

```
abcdef,defabc,defcsv,csvdef
```

`yyy` is not added because it is having repeated strings

How to achieve?

Comment: The question is very unclear. If you are not comfortable with English, please  use Google translate to frame the question from your native language. It would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use nested loops to iterate over all the pairs of words (you could also use `itertools.product()`). Then check if there are any characters in common between the words.

```
for word1 in l:
    for word2 in l:
        if not any(c in word1 for c in word 2):
            print(word1+word2)
```

Comment: The above answer does not work for me!. Please some one help me to achieve.

Comment: I don't understand the criteria for which strings should be included in the result. You said "if one string of characters doesn't exist in another string". That doesn't explain why `yyy` isn't included, since those characters aren't in the other string.